# Tooltip on each radio button and label in group, ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

working on extjs 2.3, trying to get tooltips to appear on a radio group when a user either hovers over the radio button or the label

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();
var radios = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({
        id: 'someId',
        fieldLabel: 'Period',
        columns: 2,
        items: [
            { id: 'am_box', boxLabel: 'AM', name: 'period', inputValue: 'am', tooltip: 'some am message', checked: true },
            { id: 'pm box', boxLabel: 'PM', name: 'period', inputValue: 'pm', tooltip: 'some pm message' }
        ]
    });
```

can't see anything in the documentation around tooltips and radio buttons, can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: Don't you just want a title attribute?

Comment: I'm new to ext so am not sure what you mean, can you explain or show an example thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I took @isherwood advise and looked into title attribute and came up with the following solution.

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();
var radios = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({
    id: 'someId',
    fieldLabel: 'Period',
    columns: 2,
    items: [
        { id: 'am_box', boxLabel: 'AM', listeners: me.setRadioQtip('some am message'), name: 'period', inputValue: 'am', checked: true },
        { id: 'pm box', boxLabel: 'PM', listeners: me.setRadioQtip('some am message'), name: 'period', inputValue: 'pm' }
    ]
});

setRadioQtip: function ( t )
{
    var o = {
        render: function()
        {
            var id  = Ext.get(Ext.DomQuery.select('#x-form-el-'+this.id+' div'));
            Ext.QuickTips.register(
            {   
                target:  id.elements[id.elements.length - 1].id, 
                text: t,
                dismissDelay: 5000
            });
        },
        destroy: function()
        {
            var id = Ext.get(Ext.DomQuery.select('#x-form-el-'+this.id+' div'));
            Ext.QuickTips.unregister(id.elements[id.elements.length-1].id);
        }        
    }
    return o;
}
```

the tooltip now appears around the radio button and label however it is a bit hit and miss all depends on where you hover, the id is pointing at class="x-form-radio-wrap-inner " which holds the button and label, I was able from there to get the actual button and label ids and point the quick tip at these instead so it works exactly how I want it to.

Hope this helps somebody else out in the future!

Answer (score 4):

For almost every labeled field component ExtJS provides an optional Template configuration to insert in the field markup.

According to documentation you can add the following to your code in this particular case:

`boxLabelAttrTpl: 'data-qtip="my radio item tip"',`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tooltip on the actual radio button then you can use the inputAttrTpl config.

```js
{
  xtype: 'radio',
  inputAttrTpl: 'data-qtip="Your tooltip",
}
```

You may need to initialize the QuickTipManager to enable tooltips if you are not using an `Ext.app.Application`:

```js
Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();
```